# Extracting data from one layer using a second layer as the bounding area

Tags: qgis

Seems like this should be straight forward but I'm not finding it.

I have two layers:  A Boundary Layer and a Street Layer.  The Boundary layer contains multiple jurisdictions and the Street layer contains multiple streets.  Both files are shapefiles.

I'm trying to extract into a .CSV file the data for the Streets who are contained within one specific jurisdiction.

I've done this with the an old version of ArcView in the distant past but now have QGIS as my available tool.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the following steps:

1. Use the selection tool  to select the specific jurisdiction

[image]

2. Use `Select by Location` from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector selection tools -> Select by location`

[image]

A. Choose line layer (street lines) in the `Layer to select from`

B. Choose the Polygon (jurisdiction boundary) in the `Additional layer (intersection layer)`

C. Choose the suitable method in `Geometric predicate` (`within`) might be the one to choose, but you can test other methods if the output is not the desired one.

3. Save the selected street lines as CSV by right click the street lines from the table of content `->` choose `CSV` in the `Format` `->` check `Save only selected features`. If you want xy geometry, then keep everything as it is in the `Layer options -> Geometry` `AS_XY`, if you don't want xy coordinates, then change `AS_XY` to `Default`, and click `OK` after specifying the output file name.

[image]